# Flag for duplicate user+question considered invalid?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged the following question yesterday for attention (not closure): 
[Get path of current module after using RemoteThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719840/get-path-of-current-module-after-using-remotethread)

In my explanation I stated that the OP is the same OP as of the following thread (something which was also stated by the OP):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719140/get-path-of-current-module-after-using-remotethread/

I wondered whether or not the accounts/questions could be merged to not have duplicates lying around. I see now that this flag was considered invalid and I wonder why.

Should one not flag such cases for attention? Are such merges impossible? I'm not arguing about the invalid flag, but would like to know what the proper procedure (if any) would be. Mainly because I stumble upon more cases like this from time to time.

Comment: I also merged those two questions then closed and deleted the original less detailed one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree; that is the same user.

I'm not sure why the flag was dismissed as valid; we get a lot of flags so perhaps that one was mishandled. For example -- this month alone there have been 31,557 flags to date.

Anyway, I merged the user, and moderators do have the ability to merge users so feel free to continue flagging dupe users.